# How to check if key has been clicked more than once or to find out how long a key has been pressed for c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
if(GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().position.y >= -2.4){
     abletojump = false;
}
else{
    abletojump = true;
}
if(abletojump == true && Input.GetKey("space")){
     transform.Translate(Vector3.up * 10 * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

I have made it so that if the object is over a specific height they shouldn't be allowed to jump. But it seems that when ever I set that height range it always seems to go lower than that so it repeatedly keeps jumping in the air. anyways knowing how to tell if a key has been pressed the an amount of times or to detect how long a key has been pressed for would really help.

Thanks.

Comment: So add some member variables to your code to keep track of that?

Answer (score -1):

Save the time when button is pushed `Input.GetKeyDown` and while the button is held down`Input.GetKey` find the difference between `currentTime` and the time that the button was pushed.

```
float timeThatshouldBePassed = 5f;
float pushStart = 0f;

void Update() {
  if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) {
      pushStart = Time.time;
  }
  if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space)) {
    if ((Time.time - pushStart) > timeThatshouldBebPassed) {
      // doSomethings
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks but "pushStart" never restarts so when the time reaches >5 i can never jump again.

Comment: we are resetting it `pushStart = Time.time` everytime that the button is pushed